# How do I process a form from within Jquery overlay

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok so here's what I'm trying to do in simple terms. I've a table with a checkbox and input field in every row. There's a button at the bottom that allows the user to batch edit all the checked rows. When the button is clicked, an overlay (using Jquery Tools) opens (or rather, unhides), with a single input field and a button.

```
<div id="batch">
<form>
<label>New text:</label>
<input type="text" />
</form>
</div>

<table>
<tr><td><input id="1234" type="checkbox" /></td><td>Some text (from database)</td></tr>
etc…
```

So far, so good.

What I'm trying to understand now is how to structure this to actually do something with the pertinent data (i.e. the IDs of the checked rows and the new value).

In other words, how do I make something happen when the user clicks the button?

Comment: look into jquery `.post`

Comment: Could you show some HTML code of the form?

Comment: @rock-ass edited post to include some code

Comment: After the user clicks the button --> One of the options : Iterate over all the checkboxes, make a concatenated string of all the ids that are checked. Then, post this concatenated string and value_to_update to your server via jQuery ajax form submit or via jQuery/ajax. Explode the ids on your server and apply the values.

Comment: http://designm.ag/tutorials/jquery-forms/ here's a lot of tutorials, try looking at them, this is a basic problem so i think there is no need to write one when there is hundreds of them already :)